# Which item was viewed the most?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my csv file

[image]

I want to check which items has the most events. Events are view, addtocart and transaction.
For example my output should be:

Itemid 33334 has 48741 views (33334 has the most views)

Itemid 78451 has 844 addtocart

Itemid 26564 has 526 transactions

My code is wrong. How I could the most events related to the itemdid.

```
  events = df["event"].value_counts().groupby(['itemid']).mean()
  print(events)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can groupby on both of them

```
 df.groupby(['itemid','event']).count()
```

to have a column for count, you can do this

```
import numpy as np
df['counts'] = np.zeros(len(df))
filtered_df = df.groupby(['itemid','event']).count()
```

You can query for `view` event as

```
filtered_df.query("event=='view'")
```

Comment: With `events = df.groupby(['itemid','event']).count().sort_values(['timestamp'], ascending=False).head(3)
print(events)` Is there something like  ....(events='views') so that I get only views for events? :)

Comment: You can use `.query("event=='view'")`

Comment: I have updated the answer, you might need to have count column as well. So I updated how to do it